# Alamofire: responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.inputDataNilOrZeroLength)

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am trying to upload data through alamofire including images. But it returns

> responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.inputDataNilOrZeroLength)

--
        and my code is ,

```
    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in

            multipartFormData.append((userid?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8))!, withName: "user_id")

            multipartFormData.append((self.addUserBtnTag?.description.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8))!, withName: "slot")
}, to: urlString, method: .post, encodingCompletion: { (result) in
 switch result {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):

                upload.responseJSON { response in

                    print(response.result)
                    print("Response : ", response)

                    if response.result.isSuccess
                    {
                        let JSON = response.result.value as? NSDictionary

                        print("EditJSON : ", JSON!)
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
            }
        })
```

But actually I am passing more than ten parameters through alamofire.

Comment: Your response is empty or nil. Try to do that in postman.

Comment: Its give the response in postman.**responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.inputDataNilOrZeroLength)** **bold** This is return as an error not as response.If the value nil then it have to give the response as missing parameter.

Comment: Can you add your postman response too ?

Comment: Don't let Postman mislead you. It happened to me once. Postman is "so good" that it's able to parse json even if there is irrelevant text outside of the top level scope braces. E.g. `blahblah {"someProperty":"someValue"}` will work on Postman, but won't work in Alamofire. So check the raw text of your response to see if you're getting parsable data.

Comment: Thanks @SharadChauhan and ** AuRis** Its clear from both of yours answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Just change from  `responseJSON` to `responseString`

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in

            multipartFormData.append((userid?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8))!, withName: "user_id")

            multipartFormData.append((self.addUserBtnTag?.description.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8))!, withName: "slot")
}, to: urlString, method: .post, encodingCompletion: { (result) in
 switch result {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):

                upload.responseString { response in

                    print(response.result)
                    print("Response : ", response)

                    if response.result.isSuccess
                    {
                        let JSON = response.result.value as? NSDictionary

                        print("EditJSON : ", JSON!)
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
            }

        })
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this for uploading image with parameter with alamofire

```
 Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in

        let imageData: NSData? = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5) as NSData?
        if imageData != nil {

            multipartFormData.append(imageData! as Data, withName: strImageKey, fileName: "imagep.jpeg", mimeType: "imagep/jpeg")

            for (key, value) in dictParams {
                let data = "\(value)".data(using: .utf8)
                multipartFormData.append(data! as Data, withName: key)
            }
        }

    }, with: requestName,encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):

            upload.responseJSON { response in
                log.debug("Image(s) Uploaded successfully:\(response)")
                //Networking.handleApiResponse(response)
            }
        case .failure(let encodingError):
            log.debug("encodingError:\(encodingError)")
            // Networking.handleApiResponse(response)

            Util.showAlertWithMessage(msgSorry, title:"Error")
        }
        completionHandler!(encodingResult)
    }
    )
```