# Alamofire responseSerializationFailed

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am using Alamofire to make request in my swift app. All of my request were working 2 days ago and now only some of them are working. My API is working correctly, I get the correct response using Postman and in the Android version of my app.

Here is the request code

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Authorization": "\(token)",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        ]

Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in
            deactivateActivityIndicator()

            if let json = response.result.value {
                log.debug("User json: \(json)")
                let user = Mapper<User>().map(JSON: JSON(json).dictionaryObject!)
                self.delegate?.getRequestSuccessful(user!)
            }
            else{
                self.delegate?.requestError("Error occurred getting response from API")
            }
        })
```

The JSON I am requesting from my API looks as follows:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "first_name": "Test",
    "last_name": "Tester",
    "role": 1,
    "verified": true,
    "edited": "2018-08-14T11:52:31.900Z",
    "created": "2018-08-14T08:02:59.251Z"
}
```

I keep getting a `401` response as follows:

> responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character
>   0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))

I have tried change from `responseJSON` to `responseString` like in the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51535498/alamofire-responseserializationfailedalamofire-aferror-responseserializationf) but it did not fix the problem

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the same response. Try printing out the data itself like `debugPrint(String(data: response.data, encoding: .utf8))`, It may give some more clue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ALAMOFIRE : responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.inputDataNilOrZeroLength)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51535498/alamofire-responseserializationfailedalamofire-aferror-responseserializationf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue after a couple of days of searching and debugging. When entering the URL for the Alamofire request I was using the URL formatted like `https:///www.test.com`. I added an extra slash at the end as follows `https:///www.test.com/`

According to what I found, the request will get redirected to the correct URL and the headers are not sent along with the request. Thus explaining the 401 response (Unauthorized)

Answer (score 0):

Please try with JSONEncoding.default . in place of URLEncoding.default in your existing code