# Alamofire - responseSerializationFailed

Tags: ios, swift

I really need help with this one. I'm trying to do POST request using Alamofire, but for some reason I'm always getting an error from the title. When I test in POSTMAN, I'm getting okay response. Here is screenshot from POSTMAN, just to get things clearer:

[image]

And this is how I'm calling this API in code:

```
let parameters: Parameters = [
        "data": [
            "action":"homeimages"
        ]
    ]

    print("Params: \(parameters)")

    Alamofire.request(Constants.API_URL_2, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON {
        response in
        print("Response: \(response)")
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            print("Response: \(value)")
            break
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show the full logged error.

Comment: you could show us the rawValue received from server like this `if let data = response.data { let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) }` and print the string or post it here

Comment: In POSTMAN, you use form-data, but in your code, it's using json.

Comment: change  `responseJSON` to  `responseString` and it will be ok.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51537003/8294374

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I know **responseserializationfailed** error, mostly error with API itself however as you stated, you are getting response in POSTMAN please check below things :

1. URL(check small/caps well), parameters are correct(check caps and dictionary format as well)
2. Sometimes we don't need below (optional) parameter , delete this parameter and check

   ```
   encoding: JSONEncoding.default
   ```