# Alamofire POST request with nested parameters returns nothing

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, nsurlrequest

Hello I am trying to use Alamofire for my HTTP requests. It is working with parameters that are not included any nested parameter. Normally, my url is working with following on the Google Chrome.

http://111.222.33.4:12345/my_server/dispatch?cmd=ext_getReferanceData&jp=%7b%22rfName%22:%22RF_ABC%22%7d&token=123
and the decoded version of above url is

> http://111.222.33.4:12345/my_server/dispatch?cmd=ext_getReferanceData&jp={"rfName":"RF_ABC"}&token=123

It works fine when I paste it into any browser. However when I try to send following post request with Alamofire

```
    let parameters3: [String: Any] = [
        "cmd": "ext_getReferanceData",
        "jp": [
            "rfName": "RF_ABC"
        ],
        "token": "123"
    ]

    Alamofire.request("http://111.222.33.4:12345/my_server/dispatch", method: .get, parameters: parameters3, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { (response) in
    }
```

It is returning

> FAILURE:
>   responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.inputDataNilOrZeroLength)

What could be the reason of it am I sending parameters wrong or is there anything that I am missing?

Edit: I also checked other questions about the error but the problem is about parameters that I am trying to send because there is " and { in the parameters but I could not send in the request.

Comment: Currently your alamofire method .GET in code, Please change it to .POST and it will work.

Comment: @KeyurFaldu no it is not working with .POST too.

Comment: `responseString` instead of `responseJSON `

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ALAMOFIRE : responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.inputDataNilOrZeroLength)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51535498/alamofire-responseserializationfailedalamofire-aferror-responseserializationf)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51537003/8294374

Comment: I also checked these answers but the problem is about parameters I am trying to send neither responseString is not working too. @EneaDume

Answer (score 0):

have you considered printing the response being sent and confirming it that it's indeed the stuff you're trying to send?

You can do a couple of things to improve

1. Make the method .post
2. Try to use .validate() for added reliability

The way I do it is something like:

```
let submissionURL = URL(string: "https://blablabla.com/script.php")
 sendAlamofireRequest(submissionURL: submissionURL!, parameters: parameters, chosenTrackerStr: chosenTrackerString) //function call

 //function declaration
func sendAlamofireRequest(submissionURL: URL, parameters: Parameters, chosenTrackerStr: String){

    Alamofire.request(submissionURL, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).validate().responseString() { (response) in
         //actual code goes here
    }
 }
```

Maybe try to play around with the alamofire request and check its documentation to see the suggested approach :)