# Alamofire: FAILURE responseSerializationFailed

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to get the `JSON` from a URL to download using `Alamofire`.

```
Alamofire.request(requrl, method: .get, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .responseJSON { response in
            print(response.result)
            print(response.value)
            debugPrint(response)


            }
```

However the value of `response.value` is nil, and the request result status is FAILURE. The following is in the logs:

```
>[Data]: 919 bytes
[Result]: FAILURE: responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))
[Timeline]: Timeline: { "Request Start Time": 561988246.258, "Initial Response Time": 561988246.446, "Request Completed Time": 561988246.447, "Serialization Completed Time": 561988246.447, "Latency": 0.189 secs, "Request Duration": 0.189 secs, "Serialization Duration": 0.000 secs, "Total Duration": 0.190 secs
```

The JSON url in a browser returns:
[image]

php script

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
//header('Content-Type: html; charset=utf-8');
$sqlstatement = $_GET["sqlstatement"];
// Create connection
$dbConnection=mysqli_connect("***.***.gear.host","****","*****!","****");

//$sqlstatement = "SELECT * FROM reeds.tbl_user";
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  // Print error message 
  echo mysqli_connect_error();
}

// Stores SQL statement, selecting all objects from testcomputing.name


// Check to ensure results > = 1
if ($result = mysqli_query($dbConnection, $sqlstatement))
{
    // If so, then create a results array and a temporary one to hold the data
    $resultArray = array();
    $tempArray = array();

    // Loop through each row in the result set
    while($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        // Add each row into our results array
    $tempArray = $row;
     array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
    }

    // Encode the array to JSON and output the results
    echo json_encode($resultArray);
}

// Close connections
mysqli_close($dbConnection);
?>
```

Comment: There is some problem in response serialisation looking at your error log.
Make sure data from url is in correct json format.

Comment: Can you check the response content type? looks like you are not getting a JSON response. Can you try to use just `response` instead of `responseJSON` method to see the result?

Comment: Use `URLEncoding()` for *GET* requests.

Comment: Because Alamofire is expecting JSON in the result (you are using JSONEncoding), the first character of the response data should be a `{` or a `[`.

Comment: @Marcel please see updated question for what JSON returns from url

Comment: You could print the response data in the result like this: `debugPrint(String(data: response.data!, encoding: .utf8))`

Comment: @Marcel I think the issue is although the web output looks as if its JSON it is intact not, not really sure why but i have updated the question with my PHP script

Comment: You should add an else{echo json_encode(array('error'=>'NOT FOUND', 'message' => "The data was not found"));} at the end of the php file.  This will assure that something would be sent back that you can control/test/mod.  Then, if you get that 'odd' FAILURE response, you will know it is something in the signaling (though it seems you have covered that).  If you get the error, then you know something else is going on.  I think you are missing something else - perhaps in the requrl (you didn't give it {understood} but I'd look there).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51537003/8294374

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ALAMOFIRE : responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.inputDataNilOrZeroLength)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51535498/alamofire-responseserializationfailedalamofire-aferror-responseserializationf)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was associated with the hosting provider. The provider I was originally using had strange security protocols installed, as such no JSON was being returned, after switching it work perfectly.